# How to specify complicated patterns in function arguments?

Tags: pattern-matching, argument-patterns

Unfortunately, I have not found in documentation how to create complicated patterns in arguments of a function

Consider a toy example. Say, I would like to have a simple function

```
foo[c_, x_] := c*x^2
```

but `c` is to be a real number, and `x` is a list. This can be achieved in a trivial way:

```
foo[c_Real, x_List] := c*x^2
```

But how to specify conditions:

1. `c` is real number belonging to $[2.3, \sqrt{10})$
2. `x` is an integer-valued list, `Length[x]>=5`, `Min[x]>=0`, and `Max[x]<=3`

I tried to use `Condition`, but had no success

Comment: `c_Real` isn't really the right pattern here, since that's the data type for things like `0.5`. In any case, one way to express your conditions is to indeed use `Condition[]` with something like `TrueQ[23/10 <= c < Sqrt[10]] && VectorQ[x, IntegerQ] && (* your other conditions *)`.

Comment: Thanks, as I understand, you mean syntax: `foo[c_ , x_] := c x^2   /; TrueQ[c >= 23/10 &&  VectorQ[x, IntegerQ]]`? It seems this works.

Comment: Great, this works! I used this construction, but without `TrueQ[]`, simply `con1 && con2 && ... `.  And how to use this for a `Module`, not function?

Comment: look at this [cheat sheet](https://12000.org/my_notes/faq/mma_notes/MMA.htm), search the page for **some signatures collection** you will see many examples.

Comment: Thanks, Nasser, I'll explorer your great resource. At the moments, all things with patterns are resolved